# How to put figcaption on top of an image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to put a `figcaption` at the bottom of an `img` so that it is 'on top' of the image and transparent so the the images comes through.

Unfortunately, I can't make them the same width (no idea why) or put the `figcaption` on top of the the image.  If I use a negative `margin-top`, it just 'hides' underneath the image.

I've tried `z-index` and everything else I can think of but no luck so far.
Here is my code:

```css
.floatImage {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin: 15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
}

figure {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

figcaption {
  background-color: rgba(79, 44, 16, 0.6);
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -2.4em;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img class="floatImage" src="img.png">
  <figcaption>Placeholder caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For `z-index` to work, the elment must have a non-static position, like `relative` or `absolute`.
2. Remove the margins from `floatImage` for width consistency

Result:

```css
.floatImage {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

figure {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

figcaption {
  background-color: rgba(79, 44, 16, 0.6);
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -2.4em;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img class="floatImage" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
  <figcaption>Placeholder caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hey1ppd2/

Comment: Thanks, works pretty much perfectly. Good to know about z-index and position.  And how did you format the code so nicely? Stackoverflow's method has been driving me crazy..

Comment: @wolf_adventures1909 You're welcome. You could just press `ctrl+m` to open the stack snippet editor to place code properly.

Comment: Okay, will keep in mind.  Thanks again for your help.