# Center Text on multiple images

Tags: html, css

I need to add centre text on multiple images of different sizes within their own  tags in a container div.

This is how my HTML and CSS is setup

```
<section>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col ">
        <div class="container gallery">
            <img class="sports" src="img/block1Sports.jpg">
            <h3 class="text1" >Sports</h3>
            <img id="wellness" src="img/block2Wellness.jpg">
            <h3 class="text1" >wellness</h3>
            <img id="expeditions" src="img/block3Expeditions.jpg">
            <h3 class="text1" >expeditions</h3>
            <img id="games" src="img/block4Games.jpg">
            <h3 class="text1" >games</h3>
            <img id="culture" src="img/block5Culture.jpg">
            <h3 class="text1" >culture</h3>
            <img id="beauty" src="img/block6Beauty.jpg">
            <h3 class="text1" >beauty</h3>
            <img id="travelling" src="img/block7Travelling.jpg">
            <h3 class="text1" >travelling</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

All these images have a single text messages which should all be centred, appreciate your help.

[Here is a snap example of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZOxs.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put figcaption on top of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942115/how-to-put-figcaption-on-top-of-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<img>`, put your image in a div container using css `background-image:url('');`. Then use `display:flex;` (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on this div to position your text vertically and horizontally centered.

HTML

```
<section>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col ">
        <div class="container gallery">
          <div class="imageWithCenteredText sports">
            <h3 class="text1" >Sports</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.imageWithCenteredText {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sports {
    background-image: url('img/block1Sports.jpg');
    width: 500px; /* PICTURE WIDTH */
    height: 500px;  /* PICTURE HEIGHT */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i added each picture within a <div class="col-md-4"> respectfully.
Then class="text1" with CSS:   position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    color: #fff  ;

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
            .gallery-item {
                position: relative;
            }
            .gallery-item img {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .gallery-item h3 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col ">
                    <div class="container gallery">
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img class="sports" src="img/block1Sports.jpg">
                            <h3 class="text1" >Sports</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img id="wellness" src="img/block2Wellness.jpg">
                            <h3 class="text1" >wellness</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img id="expeditions" src="img/block3Expeditions.jpg">
                            <h3 class="text1" >expeditions</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img id="games" src="img/block4Games.jpg">
                            <h3 class="text1" >games</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img id="culture" src="img/block5Culture.jpg">
                            <h3 class="text1" >culture</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img id="beauty" src="img/block6Beauty.jpg">
                            <h3 class="text1" >beauty</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img id="travelling" src="img/block7Travelling.jpg">
                            <h3 class="text1" >travelling</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get more information at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp